# How to automate the creation of Table data on Jmeter when using aggregate report?

Tags: performance, testing, automation, jmeter, automated-tests

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3jbC.png)I want to obtain the Table Data created by the aggregate report used in Jmeter 5.3 but i cannot find the way. I don't know if i can can do it using a BeanShell PostProcessor or executing my script in the terminal.

I didn't found the way to get this solution please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), you can automate the process of generating the CSV version of the aggregate report from the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) by executing the following command:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv /desired/path/to/aggregate/report.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

P.S. Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Comment: Hi Dimitri!

i need the "Save Table data" automated. I know that i can generate de aggregate report but that report does not have the metrics combined the way that de Table Data does.